# How do I create the largest possible space habitat for humans?

Tags: biology, physics, space, hard-science, astrophysics

So I'm making a post-FTL world in which humans are the first, and so far only, species to explore the stars. It's thousands (if not millions) of years in the future, and we've become post scarcity. Antimatter, Antienergy, Fusion, Fission, genetic engineering, molecular 3D printing, and FTL light travel have all been developed and perfected. Basically the only thing we can't do is manipulate gravity freely.

What form does my space habitat take to house the largest population of humans in a world where the limiting factors are only the forces of gravity vs structural integrity?

Restrictions:

- No Handwavium material, but feel free to create structures completely out of carbon nanotubes, gallium, gold, or any other material provided it won't decay fast enough to hurt structural integrity or irradiate people to death.
- Structure should be made to last 1,000 years minimum.
- Any given enclosure need to be connected to another enclosure with a walkway that can be walked through in a manageable amount of time, like an hour or less. It's a quirk that future humans have, wanting to be as closely together as possible.
- It should be expandable when possible.

Assume:

- Logistics such as food, water, and electricity are all self contained in any given structure using '(S)ignificantly (A)dvanced (T)echnology [that it] appear[s]to be magic.' No need to worry about it I'll work around whatever.
- Any size planet, black hole, or other astronomical body can be found and moved or made using S.A.T., so long as the body can exist at all. I.E.: Any star with enough mass to collapse into a black hole will, but any star below that size can be found and used.
- Radiation coming from space is neutralized. However, if you use something radioactive like a sun in your design, you need to account for the mass of appropriate radiation shields.
- Construction time is no object.

Given these perameters, how do I make the larges livable habitat possible?

Some possible forms the station could take:

- An orb that encircles a black hole to use for gravity.
- A series of super dense planetary cores that creates gravity for each consecutive floor building outwards in layers that encircle the entire planet until gravity is too weak, and then the outermost layer is connected to the outermost layer of another structure build around a planetary core.
- A hollow cylinder surrounding the barycenter of a series of planets that all give off ~1g.

I am only looking for the calculations regarding structural integrity, and maximizing size of living space. It doesn't matter how I'm going to make it, I just want to know what shape I should make it in.

Comment: There is no way to answer a question about what could be done millions of years into the future, especially if you throw physics out the window with ftl. Also, constructing the largest possible maximizes one and only one thing: size. There are other important parameters. Making the largest one physically possible makes no sense. But that's just a side note, it doesn't have to make sense to be fun

Comment: Hard science can't apply when you've given a situation that isn't possible by what we currently consider hard science.

Comment: @Separatrix The hard science is just the physics behind a structure suspended in space that has a gravitational field acting upon it in such a way that it is livable by human standards. Perfectly calculable.

Comment: @Raditz_35 The largest possible structure makes sense in this scenario, since I'm isolating the factor that is important to me. If the parameter is heat dispersion, I add a bunch of ac units. If heating is the problem, I add heating units. if food is the problem, I have industrial sized 3d printers making beef sandwiches and jello. If solar radiation is the problem, I push a planet in the way to block it. The actual thing I'm concerned about is producing a stable gravitational environment  for a vast number of humans who want to all stay physically connected for reasons not important here.

Comment: I think @Seperatrix is right. You can't have hard science if you tell us that your technology appears to be magic.

Comment: @John Locke All the hard science is based on is gravity and material strengths, the SAT is just my way of simplifying the question on what I want to know and not have to describe all the giant hydrogen powered rockets they use to move planets out of the way or create orbits and stuff. Like I could clarify that they could use lasers to heat large deposits of pure iron to make a planet with an exact dessity, but the tech doesn't actually change the answer.

Comment: In that case, you could edit your answer to explain what kind of tech you have. The fact that you mentioned magic and said time was not a concern made me think we were talking about magic, which is difficult to explain in hard-science terms.

Comment: I just have really chill humans. This structure could take dozens or hundreds of generations to build, I don't expect it to be finished in one. And basically everything is 3d printed, unless there's a reason that it has to be made some other way.

Comment: While this question says "a couple of million years in the future" it's not opinion based nor unanswerable. It's not asking us to invent new materials, but that given todays knowledge of future materials and construction methods, what could we build? The million years in the future is there only to take away any grievances like "we cant build that in the forseeable future" or "we need power generation from a Black hole and that's not feasible within x-thousand years". The best answer would be extremely simple to determine: it combines construction and materials to build the biggest habitat.

Comment: Just put an "infinite" cylinder in deep space held together by carbon nanotubes. Rotate about the center of the cylinder and have everyone live on the inside edge. Now you just need to know the end "gravity" you want and CNT tensile strength and you can find the cylinder radius. Even then it doesn't matter much because your cylinder is so long.

Comment: @Clay Deitas  What you need to do is to look up Larry Niven's article "Bigger than Worlds" (1974) for ideas.  - http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?133302  - And I remember an article sometime later about building a ring around Jupiter at the right height to have one Earth gravity.  One could also build a ring around The Sun at the right height to have one Earth gravity.  As for building planets see https://planetplanet.net/the-ultimate-solar-system/

Comment: I'd really like this question reopened.

Comment: @ClayDeitas I think your going to need more restrictions than that. If I have a space habitat that is infinitely large, then gravity will act on each point of my space habitat equally, because it is being pulled in every direction by an infinite amount of mass right? As long as its uniformly dense in every direction your largest space station can be infinitely large.

Comment: @Shadowzee How large do I have to make it for its own gravity to be enough to support human life? If its pulled in all directions, do the people live inside spheres and walk around the inside? Will there be no gravity in walkways connecting them? Will the edges of the habitat collapse because they won't have gravitational forces pulling them away? If I use stabilizing thrusters to counteract this will it hurt the rest of the habitat? Since it's impossible to have something be truly infinitely large that doesn't actually answer my question either.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yk-Ivm9MhYs

Comment: @ClayDeitas You absolutely **_must_** read Larry Niven's [Bigger then Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigger_Than_Worlds), then you probably don't need any answers from us given the last couple of options presented in that essay.

Comment: @ClayDeitas - Your structure will need to be the size of a planet (larger due to low density).  However, it will collapse in on itself before it gets that big.  You are better off building your ecumenopolis on a planet you find on Craig's List.  For plans, look to Giedi Prime, Trantor, and/or Coruscant.  I'm sure someone has built a 1:1 scale replica of at least one of them.  Those can be found on Craig's List or eBay.

Answer (score 3):

## Order a planet from Amazon

You said you can move planets.  You have FTL.  3D molecular printing means you can build anything. That means,  you can terraform planets.

I believe there would exist a company that makes them in your future. There could be one whose headquarters would are on Magrathea.

Just - don't order a Weyland-Yutani one.

Comment: Although the references are nice, this doesn't really answer my question at all.